# Objection.js - Realtion with pivot table

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, knex.js, objection.js

i'm having hard times understanding how I should model many-to-many relationships in objections.js.

Basically I have an app with an Users, Games and UsersScore tables. A account can have score in game.

Tables are like this:

**USERS TABLE**

- id
- username

**GAMES TABLE**

- id
- name

**UsersScore TABLE**

- id
- userId
- gameId
- score

How do I create the relation?

I want to show the logged in user a list of all the games
And if he has score in the game then his score

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

This is essentially identical to the requirements outlined at [Join table extra properties](https://vincit.github.io/objection.js/recipes/extra-properties.html) in the Objection documentation. You could adapt this to create `users`, `games`, and `users_games` tables. Then your `User` model might look like this:

```
class User extends Model {
  static get relationMappings() {
    return {
      relation: Model.ManyToManyRelation,
      modelClass: Game,
      join: {
        from: 'users.id',
        through: {
          from: 'users_games.user_id',
          to: 'users_games.game_id',
          extra: ['score']
        },
        to: 'game.id'
      }
    };
  }
}
```

Here you can see that we've added an extra `score` column to our `users_games` join table. Then I imagine you would get a list of games with something like:

```
const user = await User.query().findOne({ username: 'wombatsarefluffy' });
const games = await user.$relatedQuery('games');
```

See the documentation page for an example of how to construct the migrations.